# IronPython 3 compatibility

Tags: python, python-3.x, ironpython

I love the Python language and mainly use the standard CPython 3.+ version for simple scripting and as an algorithm sandbox. Sometimes I need .NET intergration, so I use IronPython which is now in 2.7 version.

I like 3.+ better and am therefore reluctant to use the older 2.7. Is there any info on when will it be released and how difficult the migration process is expected to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is as far as I know no planned release date for 3.0 support in IronPython. The migration process for IronPython 2 -> IronPython 3 is the same as for CPython 2 -> CPython 3, afaik.

Answer (score 19):

IronPython has one big step towards Py3k support - its strings are already unicode. Many of the native modules are already in place because they were backported to Python 2.7. The re-arranged standard library is free because it's just copied from CPython.

The time-consuming part are the parser changes such as function annotations, removed `print` statement, etc. It's not terribly *hard*, but there just aren't many people with the knowledge to do it right now and those that do are pretty short on free time to do so. We are, however, extrememly willing to get others up to speed.

The more bodies that can be thrown at it, the sooner it will get done.

Comment: That's great news, I've my own start-up and strongly intend to ship some open-source freeware based on IronPython.net in browser beginning with v3.0 onwards.