# IronPython 3 support?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ironpython

Yes, I know about [IronPython 3 compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751767/ironpython-3-compatibility), but that is from two years ago. I was searching on the internet but couldn't find any information on this that is up-to-date.

So does IronPython support Python 3? If not, how many of the future imports work, and are there any Iron-specific ways to make it seem more like Python 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IronPython 3 is once again alive. An alpha for Python 3.4 was released in April 2021. It is a very active effort which is being supported by the .NET Foundation. More here: [Python 3.4 Release Notes](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/releases/tag/v3.4.0-alpha1)

Answer (score 9):

Currently it doesn't support Python3. [IronPython3 Todo](http://blog.jdhardy.ca/2013/06/ironpython-3-todo.html). All future imports supported by the standard Python 2.7 interpreter should be supported by the newest version of IronPython.

And there are no Iron-specific ways to make it seem more like Python3 as far as I know.

Comment: A big one is that IronPython strings are already Unicode by default, which is the same as Python 3.

Comment: @JeffHardy Is PyCon 2014 still the target?

Comment: @marce For a very early version, yes.

Comment: I note that PyCon 2014 was held 09-17 April. As of today (22 July), IronPython 2.7.4 for Python 2.7 is the most current stable version. Any news re Python 3 support?

Comment: @RBV - https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3 appears to be the official IronPython 3 repo. It's currently not very active (latest commit was in February 2015, which was seven months ago as I'm writing this), but that would be the project to follow if you want to be notified of when Jeff Hardy starts working on IronPython 3 again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExaScript](http://exaphaser.github.io/ExaScript/), a fork of the IN-DEVELOPMENT IronPython 3, providing standard Python libraries along with multiple specialty libraries, such as PowerCrypt4, a cryptography library, OmniBeanLib, a library containing lots of common functions, and OmniBeanEB, a rewrite of the Small Basic Library that provides almost every function necessary to build a good GUI/Console application.

Best of all, for making Windows Forms applications, use EPFramework, an included library to generate a fresh, reactive, modern UI for your project.